# Installing emacs on remote machine with limited permissions

Tags: emacs, installation

I am trying to install emacs on my profile in the remote machine (I am not in the sudoers list). I downloaded the tar file and unzipped it, ran `./configure` and then did `make`. When I do `make install`, it needs permissions to access /usr/local/share/emacs which I don't have. I was wondering if there exists an alternative way to install emacs.

I cannot run `apt-get install` as I do not have admin permissions on the remote machine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the `--prefix` argument to `./configure`.  Like `./configure --prefix=/home/YOU/local/emacs` or whatever path makes sense that you have write access to. Then run make and make install. Run `./configure --help` for more information.

Comment: Specifically, the `--prefix` value is a replacement for the `/usr/local` directory, such that everything which would have gone under there will now go under your custom dir instead when you run `make install`. Read the INSTALL file for details (and you should read this anyway).